# Connecting RESTful client to local virtual machine

Tags: java, rest, ssh, virtual-machine

I am trying to connect my desktop `Windows 10` machine with local Virtual Machine having `Ubuntu 16.04`.

I have written a RESTful client in following way to connect to this machine in following way.

```
public class NetClientGet {

    // http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/json/product/get
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/json/product/get");
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.56.101:8998/sessions");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));
            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }
            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to `ssh` into this virtual machine via `Putty`.The peculiarity is that till I don't `ssh` via `Putty` in this virtual machine, this code produces error as follows:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.mkyong.rest.client.NetClientGet.main(NetClientGet.java:22)
```

So what is actually missing in my approach of making connection?

Comment: open port in firewall ?

Comment: `Connection timed out: connect` - so you are connecting to right IP address and no firewall is restricting it?

Comment: Tried ping http://192.168.56.101:8998/sessions ?

Comment: @rkosegi I am able to open connection via putty 192.168.56.101 and port 22.This makes me feel in way that I can do this programmatically too.

Comment: @ZakiAnwarHamdani yes.this ip is getting pinged and also whole code is running when once I ssh it via putty

Comment: Port 22 is opened by default. Check firewall in VM

Comment: Oh, so you mean this code is running inside Ubuntu.... And what about machine (192.168.56.101)? Which one is that?

Comment: Your network configuration doesn't look correct. Looks like a case of SSH tunnel that is allowing it to work when you use putty. Guess when you are connecting through SSH, you are enabling SSH tunnel to the TCP port allowing your calls to be successful. So the first question is, is your server (VM hosting the REST service) running on port 8998? Is there any firewall on host 192.168.57.101, and if so, is port 8998 open for TCP traffic there? Do a telnet as telnet 192.168.57.101 8998, does it open up without putty session?

Comment: @Gautam I have made 2 adapter for VM, one is NAT other is  Virtual Box Host-Only Ethernet adapter.And then I am `ssh` ing via this 192.168.56.101 which was assigned to this VM due to this setting. There is one server utility which runs on 8998 port inside this VM

Comment: @UtkarshSaraf, can you check the things I mentioned. From your host machine, open a terminal and do a telnet to the VM on port 8998. Also, in your code there is a commented line that says port 8080. Is your server (web/app server) running on port 8998 or 8080?